# How do I make a Spring ApplicationContext available for another class's unit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing

I have a `SpringContext` class which implements `ApplicationContextAware` so that I can access Spring beans from a regular Java class that isn't managed by Spring:

```
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * Returns the Spring managed bean instance of the given class type if it exists.
     * Returns null otherwise.
     * @param beanClass
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {

        // store ApplicationContext reference to access required beans later on
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }

}
```

This works well when running the actual application, but during unit testing the `context` object is null, so `getBean()` returns a NPE.

The `getBean()` method is being called by a spy in the test class, but not directly, i.e. the spy has a mocked dependency which then calls this method.

I've tried making the test class `ApplicationContextAware` but that doesn't help, and neither does `@Inject`ing the `ApplicationContext`. How can I make sure that the `context` object is initialized?

Comment: The SpringContext class is a dependency of the class you are testing? Or you are testing the SpringContext?

Comment: The SpringContext class is a dependency of the one I'm testing, more specifically a dependency of a dependency

Comment: It's a integration test or a unit test? If it's a unit test I recommend you to mock the behaviour of all the dependencies of the class your are testing (Subject Under Test)